# Spotfire C# SDK: Why the Remove() method of ColoringCollection object doesnt seem to work?

Tags: c#, sdk, spotfire

I have pretty annoying problem. :)

```
visual = context.ActiveVisualReference;            
TablePlot tablePlot = visual.As<TablePlot>();            
colorings = tablePlot.Colorings;            
categories = colorings.GetCategories();            
coloring1 = colorings.GetColoringForCategory(categories[0]);            
coloring2 = colorings.GetColoringForCategory(categories[1]);            
coloring3 = colorings.GetColoringForCategory(categories[2]);            
category2 = categories[2];            
bool removed = colorings.Remove(coloring2);
```

This is the C# code I execute at the custom Tool level and the problem is that I do not see any effect within the Web Professional (using 5.5) 
of the Remove method execution.

According to the documentation the method should remove the custom coloring from visualisation and it does NOT.

Perhaps it is needed to call some method that refreshes view but I didnt manage to locate it.

Please help. :)

http://stn.spotfire.com/dxp/html/M_Spotfire_Dxp_Application_Visuals_ConditionalColoring_ColoringCollection_Remove.htm

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried tablePlot.Colorings = colorings at the end of your code ? What is the value of "removed" at the end of your code ?

In ironPython this one works:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import TablePlot
print myVisual.Title  
myTablePlot = myVisual.As[TablePlot]();
print myTablePlot.Title      
myColorings = myTablePlot.Colorings;            
myCategories = myColorings.GetCategories();  
print myCategories.Count
myColorings.Remove(myColorings.GetColoringForCategory(myCategories[1]))
```

Comment: When I tried setting tablePlot.Colorings to colorings I got error msg saying Property or indexer 'Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals.TablePlot.Colorings' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only